# grafana plotting with multiple fields

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have some data like this which I am putting in influx DB.

```
measurement userA=10,userB=20,userC=30 1475777099000000000
measurement userZ=11,userA=12,userB=31 1475777199000000000
```

is it possible to dynamically pick up userA,B,C,Z for a grafana plot? or shall I change my schema?

Comment: have you tried to solve this with templating ? http://docs.grafana.org/reference/templating/

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably consider changing your schema so that `userA`, `userB`, `userC`, `userZ` are tags with a single field called value.

For example:

```
measurement,user=A value=10 1475777099000000000
measurement,user=B value=20 1475777099000000000
measurement,user=C value=30 1475777099000000000

measurement,user=Z value=11 1475777199000000000
measurement,user=A value=12 1475777199000000000
measurement,user=B value=31 1475777199000000000
```

This way you can `GROUP BY user` and dynamically pick up on each of the users.